# Wildly different performance for CTE vs. duplicated table expression

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, optimization, cte

I have a view written like

```
create view v1 as 
with conn_query as (xxx)
select stuff from conn_query where some_cond
union
select stuff from conn_query where some_other_cond
```

But suddenly querying this view became very slow (10 seconds for a result of 2 records), even though the 
single queries in the union where very fast (milliseconds). Apparently the union caused xxx to be 
fully evaluated without pushing down the arguments (10 seconds is about also the time it takes to `select count(*) from v1`)

Rewriting the view to

```
create view v1 as 
select stuff from (xxx) where some_cond
union
select stuff from (xxx) where some_other_cond
```

fixed this. Unfortunately, this makes now the SQL xxx appear twice which is a bit ugly.

So now I'm curious if on a conceptual level, is there a good reason for this behaviour?

This is with Oracle 11.2.0.4.0

UPDATE/DUPLICATE:

I got exactly the expected fast behaviour with the cte variant by using

```
create view v1 as 
with conn_query as (select /*+INLINE*/ xxx)
select stuff from conn_query where some_cond
union
select stuff from conn_query where some_other_cond
```

as suggested in https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/172559/137386. This undocumented hint prevents Oracle from trying to be smart and materialzing the CTE just because it is accessed more than once.

Comment: What's wrong with using an `OR`?

Comment: @vérace right how I simplified it OR would make sense. In the actual query different source columns get selected into the same result columns.

Comment: You can never give us too much information! :-)